# I am getting the following error when using connection.execute() using sql alchemy in python

Tags: python, sql

> ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near
>   "FROM" LINE 1: ....id = h.sender_user_id AND sentiment IN ("+","-")
>   FROM "User...

```
[SQL: 'SELECT u.id as userid, CASE WHEN h.receiver_user_id = u.id THEN "Given" ELSE "Received" END AS Type, h.sentiment as sentiment, h.context as context,"2016-08-06 00:00:00" as time_period WHERE u.id = h.receiver_user_id OR u.id = h.sender_user_id AND sentiment IN ("+","-") FROM "User" u, "HoorahTransaction" h GROUP BY (userid,Type,sentiment,context)']
```

Comment: What's your sql statement that causes you to get this error?

Comment: `FROM` has to be before `WHERE`.

Comment: SELECT u.id AS userid,
       CASE
           WHEN h.receiver_user_id = u.id THEN 'Given'
           ELSE 'Received'
       END AS TYPE,
       h.sentiment AS sentiment,
       h.context AS context,
       "06/08/2016" AS time_period
WHERE (u.id= h.receiver_user_id
       OR u.id=h.sender_user_id)
  AND sentiment IN ("+",
                    "-")
  FROM public."User" u,
       public."HoorahTransaction" h
GROUP BY userid,
         TYPE,
         sentiment,
         context

Comment: oh sorry, you're right furas. Thanks a lot. Im just beginning my coding journey as of now

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out the sql query

```
SELECT u.id AS userid,
       CASE
           WHEN h.receiver_user_id = u.id
                AND h.sender_user_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Received'
           WHEN h.sender_user_id=u.id THEN 'Given'
           ELSE NULL
       END AS TYPE,
       h.sentiment AS sentiment,
       h.context AS context,
       '{0}' AS time_period,
       COUNT(*) AS value
FROM "User" u,
     "HoorahTransaction" h
WHERE (u.id= h.receiver_user_id
       OR u.id=h.sender_user_id)
  AND sentiment IN ('+',
                    '-')
  AND h.created>'{0}'
  AND h.created<'{1}'
GROUP BY userid,
         TYPE,
         sentiment,
         context
```